# Using a function object as an argument for numba njit function

Tags: python, numba

I want to make a general function, which takes a function object as an argument.

One of the simplest cases:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
@nb.njit()
def test(a, f=np.median):
    return f(a)

test(np.arange(10), np.mean)
```

gives error, although `test(np.arange(10))` works as expected.

The error:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
non-precise type pyobject
[1] During: typing of argument at <ipython-input-54-52cead0f097d> (5)

File "<ipython-input-54-52cead0f097d>", line 5:
def test(a, f=np.median):
    return f(a)
    ^

This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 1: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>

This is not usually a problem with Numba itself but instead often caused by
the use of unsupported features or an issue in resolving types.
```

Is this not allowed or am I missing something?

Comment: Please include the error you get in the question

Comment: Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45976662/speed-up-function-that-takes-a-function-as-argument-with-numba. It states that numba doesn't support functions as arguments

Comment: I just removed the numba import as well as the `@nb.njit()` line and your function works as intended, so I can only assume that numba cannot deal with numpy functions as arguments as of now

Comment: @sshashank124 I couldn't add the error message because StackOverflow keeps giving me errors saying "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."... I will try to add small part of the error message now. And thanks for the link! Maybe I should hard-code many different functions which calculates mean/median/... separately.

Comment: Every function which should be passed to a compiled function has to be compiled. eg. you can change the function to `test(a, f)` and passing  a compiled function like `f=nb.njit(lambda a: np.median(a))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using functions as arguments is tricky with numba and quite expensive. This is mentioned in the [Frequently Asked Questions: "1.18.1.1. Can I pass a function as an argument to a jitted function?"](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.46.0/user/faq.html#can-i-pass-a-function-as-an-argument-to-a-jitted-function):

> ### 1.18.1.1. Can I pass a function as an argument to a jitted function?
>
> As of Numba 0.39, you can, so long as the function argument has also been JIT-compiled:
>
> ```
> @jit(nopython=True)
> def f(g, x):
>     return g(x) + g(-x)
> result = f(jitted_g_function, 1)
> ```
>
> However, dispatching with arguments that are functions has extra overhead. If this matters for your application, you can also use a factory function to capture the function argument in a closure:
>
> ```
> def make_f(g):
>     # Note: a new f() is created each time make_f() is called!
>     @jit(nopython=True)
>     def f(x):
>         return g(x) + g(-x)
>     return f
> f = make_f(jitted_g_function)
> result = f(1)
> ```
>
> Improving the dispatch performance of functions in Numba is an ongoing task.

This means you have the option to use a function factory:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def test(a, func=np.median):
    @nb.njit
    def _test(a):
        return func(a)
    return _test(a)

>>> test(np.arange(10))
4.5
>>> test(np.arange(10), np.min)
0
>>> test(np.arange(10), np.mean)
4.5
```

Or to wrap the function argument as jitted-function before passing it in as argument:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit()
def test(a, f=np.median):
    return f(a)

@nb.njit
def wrapped_mean(a):
    return np.mean(a)

@nb.njit
def wrapped_median(a):
    return np.median(a)

>>> test(np.arange(10))
4.5
>>> test(np.arange(10), wrapped_mean)
4.5
>>> test(np.arange(10), wrapped_median)
4.5
```

Both options have quite a bit of boilerplate and aren't as straight-forward as one might hope.

The function-factory approach also repeatedly creates and compiles functions, so if you often call it with the same function as argument you could use a dictionary to store the known compiled functions:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

_precompiled_funcs = {}

def test(a, func=np.median):
    if func not in _precompiled_funcs:
        @nb.njit
        def _test(arr):
            return func(arr)
        result = _test(a)
        _precompiled_funcs[func] = _test
        return result
    return _precompiled_funcs[func](a)
```

The other approach (using the wrapped and jitted functions) also has some overhead, however it's not really noticeable as long as the arrays you pass in have a significant number of elements (>1000).

If the function you've showed is really the function that you wanted to use I wouldn't use numba on it at all. With such simple tasks that don't exercise the strength of numba (indexing and iterating arrays or heavy number crunching) using Python + NumPy should be faster (or as fast) and much easier to debug and understand:

```
import numba as nb

def test(a, f=np.median):
    return f(a)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great reply! Answer to the last part of your reply: What I wanted to do was to give certain functions to a sigma-clipping function (not only for my own practice but also for my research), cuz the currently available ones were too slow for my purpose (~1000 images, median combine with sigma clipping and error calculation). I found it was once tested/discussed before in ``ccdproc`` too. For now, after reading some materials, I have decided to hardcode the ``f`` function as median.