# Random array generation using Numba wrapper

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Suppose I want to generate an array using `njit` which is a library of Numba. The following approach is throwing an error and I have no idea why. I followed this from [speed up function that takes a function as argument with numba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45976662/speed-up-function-that-takes-a-function-as-argument-with-numba).

```html
import numpy as np
from numba import prange, njit

def numpy_random(n):
    return np.random.normal(size=n)
    

s=np.zeros(n)
def call_func(func):  # only take func
    func = njit(func)   # compile func in nopython mode!
    @njit
    def inner(x):
        return func(x)
    return inner

cf = call_func(numpy_random)
for i in range(k):
    s += cf(n*3)
print(np.mean(s))
```

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abhigyan/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/envs/ltesim/timer.py", line 51, in <module>
    s += cf(n*3)
  File "/home/abhigyan/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/envs/ltesim/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 468, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "/home/abhigyan/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/envs/ltesim/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 409, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<built-in method normal of numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState object at 0x7fa4cd469340>) found for signature:
 
 >>> normal(size=int64)
 
There are 4 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 4 did not match due to:
  Overload in function '_OverloadWrapper._build.<locals>.ol_generated': File: numba/core/overload_glue.py: Line 129.
    With argument(s): '(size=int64)':
   Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
     TypingError: unsupported call signature
  raised from /home/abhigyan/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/envs/ltesim/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typing/templates.py:439

During: resolving callee type: Function(<built-in method normal of numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState object at 0x7fa4cd469340>)
During: typing of call at /home/abhigyan/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/envs/ltesim/timer.py (11)


File "timer.py", line 11:
def numpy_random(n):
    return np.random.normal(size=n)
    ^

During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function numpy_random at 0x7fa4c6f40160>))
During: typing of call at /home/abhigyan/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/envs/ltesim/timer.py (46)

During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function numpy_random at 0x7fa4c6f40160>))
During: typing of call at /home/abhigyan/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/envs/ltesim/timer.py (46)


File "timer.py", line 46:
    def inner(x):
        return func(x)
        ^
```

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the error, Numba basically reports `No implementation of function [...] found for signature normal(size=int64)` and then `unsupported call signature`.  Thus, Numba does not support calling `normal` with a `size` attribute. This is actually [**documented**](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html?highlight=supported#distributions).

A simple way to reproduce the error is to execute this code:

```py
@njit('(int64,)')
def numpy_random(n):
    return np.random.normal(size=n)
```

A simple solution is to create an array, fill it and then return it:

```py
# @njit should not be used if in the context of the initial code
@njit('(int64,)')
def numpy_random(n):
    out = np.empty(n)
    for i in range(n):
        out[i] = np.random.normal()
    return out
```

Note that there is no reason for Numba to be particularly faster than Numpy here. It might even be slower on some platform since Numpy can use a more optimized implementation than Numba on them.