# How to pass an array containing functions as a parameter into njit?

Tags: python, numba

I would like to pass an array which contains a list of numba compiled functions as a parameter into an `njit` method. In my attempt to do so, I encountered the following error: `non-precise type array(pyobject, 1d, C)`.

I'm able to pass a numba compiled function as parameter into an `njit` method, but i'm unable to do so if the numba compiled functions are stored in an array.

Is there a way to pass an array of functions as parameter into njit function? or something along the lines of type casting the array so numba knows the content of the array

`np.array([function1, function2], dtype=function)`?

Here's a sample of my code

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit()
def function1(x, y):
    return x > y

@njit()
def function2(x, y):
    return x < y

@njit()
def main(inputArray):
    print(inputArray[0](1,2))
    print(inputArray[1](1,2))

functionArray = np.array([function1, function2])
main(functionArray)
```

Error message

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
non-precise type array(pyobject, 1d, C)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45976662/speed-up-function-that-takes-a-function-as-argument-with-numba

Comment: I'm able to pass a function as parameter into njit, but i'm unable to pass an array of functions as parameter into njit.

Comment: This is *not possible*. Numpy does not support storing functions as native types. In fact, Numpy cannot implement that because 1) the type of the function is specific to the target function and Numpy cannot implement the infinite amount of types (Numpy is compiled before the user-code and does not include a JIT), 2) Numpy is not dependent of Numba so it cannot store Numba function as native types. It stores it in CPython object. CPython objects cannot be read/written from njitted functions. Not to mention Numba is not very useful without njitted functions.

Comment: Put it shortly, using arrays of function means you are stuck with objects and so with slow code because calling functions from object is inherently slow. Cython may help but still, you cannot store the functions in a Numpy array as native type. I advise you using a lower-level language, like C/C++, for such a thing. Numba/CPython is not well-suited for that.

Comment: @JérômeRichard thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I was afraid that the functions can only be stored as object type in an array, which will not work in njit :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to pass variable number of arguments to function (but still, you get a warning message):

```py
import numba

T = numba.float64(
    numba.float64,
    numba.float64,
)


@numba.njit(T)
def function1(x, y):
    return x > y


@numba.njit(T)
def function2(x, y):
    return x < y


@numba.njit
def main(*inputArray):
    print(inputArray[0](1.0, 2.0))
    print(inputArray[1](1.0, 2.0))


l = [function1, function2]
main(*l)
```

Prints:

```
0.0
1.0
```

---

EDIT: Using `numba.typed.List` - this compiles without warning.

```py
import numba

T = numba.float64(
    numba.float64,
    numba.float64,
)


@numba.njit(T)
def function1(x, y):
    return x > y


@numba.njit(T)
def function2(x, y):
    return x < y


@numba.njit
def main(inputArray):
    print(inputArray[0](1.0, 2.0))
    print(inputArray[1](1.0, 2.0))


function_sig = numba.types.FunctionType(T)

l = numba.typed.List.empty_list(function_sig, 2)
l.append(function1)
l.append(function2)

main(l)
```

Prints:

```
0.0
1.0
```

Comment: The function will be recompiled when the number of item changes. This can have a huge impact on performance and the memory usage. Even worse : the compilation time will significantly grow with the number of item passed in parameter. This is because the compiler consider the input as a structure/tuple and not an array so each item needs to be considered separately. In some cases, the compilation time can grow quadratically with the number of items (or more). While this is ok few few items (bounded), this solution should *really* not be used for many items (beside being experimental)

Comment: @JérômeRichard I've added other solution using `numba.typed.List.empty_list`. I've never used `List.empty_list()` before - does this have performance impact?

Comment: Numba lists are generally significantly slower than Numpy arrays unfortunately. First, Numba needs to compile `numba.typed.List.empty_list` like it does for njitted user functions. This can be quite slow since there are AFAIK several subfunctions to compile. Thus, the start-up time can be significant. Once the function is compiled, this is fast, but the function needs to be recompiled for each different type. Numba lists are slower than CPython list when operations are done from CPython (it is faster in njitted Numba functions though).

Comment: @AndrejKesely thank you for sharing about these experimental features. I'll test both variable arguments and typed list and use the one that's faster.

Comment: Overall, if you are familiar with C++ types, Numba Lists are AFAIK like `std::vector` and Numpy array like `std::array`. `append` is slow if the List is not preallocated with the good size. It is slower than direct indexing due to capacity checks. There are also JIT checks in List that are not done in arrays (I reported an issue long ago on this AFAIR so it might not be the case anymore). In the end, a preallocated List can be close to the performance of an array for such a use-case without considering the additional compilation overhead. Thus, this solution can be interesting.

Comment: Note that the functions needs to have the same signature since Numba List are typed as opposed to CPython ones. But this is an implicit constraint mandatory for compiled codes anyway and seems to fit the OP needs.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thank you for exhaustive clarification :)